# Installing Windows 7 with Ubuntu from a native Win8 laptop

Tags: dual-boot, uefi

Computer is a Acer aspire M5-583P-6428.
It came with windows 8 installed. 
I trashed the whole thing, made two partitions and now using Ubuntu as a primary OS.

I'd like to have Windows 7 as another OS.
--here's the problem--
Install has to be done from usb key (no dvd) - that' ok.

Bios is in UEFI, secure boot locked. It won't boot from the usb key. Yes I checked the boot order. And yes, the key/port is working.

I'm wondering: it is possible to install windows 7 on the other partition from Ubuntu?

So far, it seems like a lost cause. Thanks!

Comment: You have to boot to the Windows image and install it, then repair your grub bootloader.  However, the Windows side of things isn't able to be helped here, much, because this is not a Windows support site...

Comment: Ah! touché :)
Yes my issue is exactly that.. it won't boot the winows image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand the UEFI Secure Boot right, you need to disable the secure boot option, or use a kind of "mixed mode" to be able to boot from an unsigned Media.

So maybe the secure boot lock is what you prevent from booting from the usb key.
If you can boot the from key or external dvd drive you can install Win 7 as used. But afterwards you have to repair your grub bootloader in order to Dual boot. If not only the Win 7 bootloader is installed and you never can boot your linux.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks Kessmahat.
It's exactly what I think I have to do - disable the secure boot. But I don't know how! It is locked on Dual Boot enabled. :\ and I do not know how to affect this from Ubuntu.